# docker rabbit mq image fails to load up

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

i have a project that i am using rabbitmq image docker when i use this command in my project :

```
docker-compose -f dc.rabbitmq.yml up
```

i get the below error for failing to start the container :

```
477a2217c16b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d8fb3795026b4c81eae33f4990e8bbc7b29c877388eef6ead2aca2945074c3f3
Status: Downloaded newer image for rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
Creating rabbitmq ... done
Attaching to rabbitmq
rabbitmq    | Configuring logger redirection
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.108 [error] 
rabbitmq    | 
rabbitmq    | BOOT FAILED
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.116 [error] BOOT FAILED
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error] ===========
rabbitmq    | ===========
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error] Exception during startup:
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error] 
rabbitmq    | Exception during startup:
rabbitmq    | 
rabbitmq    |     supervisor:'-start_children/2-fun-0-'/3 line 355
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error]     supervisor:'-start_children/2-fun-0-'/3 line 355
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error]     supervisor:do_start_child/2 line 371
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error]     supervisor:do_start_child_i/3 line 385
rabbitmq    |     supervisor:do_start_child/2 line 371
rabbitmq    |     supervisor:do_start_child_i/3 line 385
rabbitmq    |     rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase/0 line 27
rabbitmq    |     rabbit_prelaunch:do_run/0 line 108
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error]     rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase/0 line 27
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error]     rabbit_prelaunch:do_run/0 line 108
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error]     rabbit_prelaunch_conf:setup/1 line 33
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error]     rabbit_prelaunch_conf:decrypt_config/2 line 404
rabbitmq    |     rabbit_prelaunch_conf:setup/1 line 33
rabbitmq    |     rabbit_prelaunch_conf:decrypt_config/2 line 404
rabbitmq    |     rabbit_prelaunch_conf:decrypt_app/3 line 425
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error]     rabbit_prelaunch_conf:decrypt_app/3 line 425
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error] throw:{config_decryption_error,{key,default_pass},badarg}
rabbitmq    | throw:{config_decryption_error,{key,default_pass},badarg}
rabbitmq    | 
rabbitmq    | 07:50:26.117 [error] 
rabbitmq    | 07:50:27.118 [error] Supervisor rabbit_prelaunch_sup had child prelaunch started with rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase() at undefined exit with reason {config_decryption_error,{key,default_pass},badarg} in context start_error
```

so what i have tried so far what trying to search for any child proccess who fails the rabbit but could not find any and removed images and container and build and up them again but again the same error .

#EDIT

here is the config file :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/rabbitmq/definitions.json:/opt/definitions.json:ro
      - ./docker/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config:ro
      - dms_rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - dms_rabbitmq_logs:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_network
    labels:
      - co.elastic.logs/module=rabbitmq
      - co.elastic.logs/fileset.stdout=access
      - co.elastic.logs/fileset.stderr=error
      - co.elastic.metrics/module=rabbitmq
      - co.elastic.metrics/metricsets=status

volumes:
  dms_rabbitmq_etc:
    name: dms_rabbitmq_etc
  dms_rabbitmq_data:
    name: dms_rabbitmq_data
  dms_rabbitmq_logs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "none"
      o: "bind"
      device: ${PWD}/storage/logs/rabbitmq

networks:
  rabbitmq_network:
    name: rabbitmq_network
```

Comment: do you have some configuration? can you post the deployment file?

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio i added the docker.rabbitmq.yml to the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was recreating an encoded password.